# Validating a Login with Email or Phone and Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.net core project I have a Login page with 2 property as

```
public class loginModel
{
    public string EmailOrPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

I just want make login page which can login with email or phonenumber but I don't know how validate this property (validate email and phoneNumber)

Any suggestion?

Comment: You would need to validate it manually in the action or create a custom validation attribute. checking to make sure it is either a valid email or phone number. then checking if it exists based on the parsed type.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for replay, i saw a site with that login page in above which has validate when I typed in field, I think it possible with jQuery

Comment: @Peyman.Vl Show me the code that you have tried so far. Then I am helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom validate attribute like this and put your validation logic in it :

```
public class EmailOrPhoneNumberAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string valueAsString = value.ToString();

        const string emailRegex = @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
        bool isValidEmail = Regex.IsMatch(valueAsString, emailRegex);

        if (isValidEmail)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        const string usaPhoneNumbersRegex = @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}";
        bool isValidPhone = Regex.IsMatch(valueAsString, usaPhoneNumbersRegex);

        if (isValidPhone)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult("Invalid email or phone number.");
    }
}
```

Usage will be simply like this :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [EmailOrPhoneNumber]
    public string EmailOrPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

- Note that **ModelState** will automatically take cares of validation.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may validate your field using a regular expression

a. Define your regex (The Email regex is the one I use and phone regex is from [PhoneAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/PhoneAttribute.cs))

```
const string RGX_Email = "^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
          "(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";
const string RGX_Phone = @"^(\+\s?)?((?<!\+.*)\(\+?\d+([\s\-\.]?\d+)?\)|\d+)([\s\-\.]?(\(\d+([\s\-\.]?\d+)?\)|\d+))*(\s?(x|ext\.?)\s?\d+)?$";
```

b. Then you can validate using the regular expression attribute

```
[RegularExpression($"{RGX_Email}|{RGX_Phone}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone or Email")]
public string EmailOrPhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

2. And on server side, you may use a code similar to this to handle your model

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.EmailOrPhoneNumber)) 
   return error message;
if(model.EmailOrPhoneNumber.Contains("@"))
   return SignInWithEmail(model);
else return SignInWithPhone(model);
```